# ruby create array from query result

Tags: ruby

What is the optimal way to create an array from query result cursor?

```
results = @db.query("SELECT * FROM mytable")
```

I would like to turn results.each into an array and store it back in results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given much context (which db gem you're using etc).

However, I can think of a couple of ways off the top of my head:

```
reuslts.to_a # might not work (depends on how you're accessing the db)

a = []
results.each { |r| a << r } # will definitely work assuming `each` is defined
```

Bear in mind that the `#query` method likely returns a generator for a good reason. Turning the results into an array would be a pointless memory hog (and time-consuming). Using `#each` is definitely preferable as it will be more efficient.